# Prevent actions before setTimeout() is over

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Im curently making a memory game and if two card matches it blocks them but if not they should flip back. The problem is that you can click on other cards even if there are two cards already flipped and if you click more cards the game goes crazy and stops working
Any idea?

here's the code
https://codepen.io/stivennpe/pen/KRxvxR?editors=1010

```
    restart ();
    bindcards();


    // to restart the game and shuffle the cards
    function restart() {
    $('.restart').on('click', function () {
    cards = shuffle($('.card'));
    $(".card").each(function() {
          $( this ).removeClass( "open match show" );
      });
      $('.deck').html(cards);
      bindcards();
    });
    }



    //to open/show the card
    function bindcards(){

      $('.card').click(function () {
     $(this).addClass('open show');
         let openCards = $('.open');
         let list = jQuery.makeArray(openCards);



         if (list.length === 2 && list[0].innerHTML ===
     list[1].innerHTML){
         $(openCards).addClass('match');
         }
         if (list.length === 2) {
           setTimeout(hola, 1000)
          function hola() {$(openCards).removeClass('open show');
         }
         }


     });
    }
```

thanks

Comment: make the clicks do nothing when you don't want them to do stuff. you can't make setTimeout prevent all other things, so find another way.

Comment: Post the whole code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like for a simple solution you could set a global variable, something like *blockClicks*

If *blockClicks* is true, do nothing when a user clicks. Reset its value to false after timeout

Answer (score 0):

There is a race condition between applying the .open class to the div element, refreshing the page, querying that element, and the user speeding their way through your game. Instead of adding the .open class to the div, hoping the page refreshes quick enough, then immediately querying against with to find out how many open cards you have, keep a local variable count. Below is the slight modification to your code

```
    function bindcards() {
  let numOfOpenCards = 0;
  $(".card").click(function(e) {
    ++numOfOpenCards;

    if(numOfOpenCards > 2)
      return;

    $(this).addClass("open show");

    let openCards = $(".open");
    let list = jQuery.makeArray(openCards);

    if (numOfOpenCards >= 2 && list && list.length >= 2 && list[0].innerHTML === list[1].innerHTML) {
      $(openCards).addClass("match");       
    }

    if (numOfOpenCards >= 2) {
      setTimeout(hola, 1000);
      function hola() {
        numOfOpenCards = 0;

        let openCards = $(".open"); 
        let list = jQuery.makeArray(openCards);
        if(list) {
          for(let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
            $(list[i]).removeClass("open show");
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

If two cards are already open, the most recent card check. The previous card check should still complete and refresh as needed.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzPBrB?editors=1010

**Additional edit**
If you do not want to use numOfOpenCards, you can use the following. Find how many are already open. If there are more than 2 already, just quit. If there are less than already flipped, add the class then query the DOM again. Anywhere numOfCards is used you can replace with list.length;

```
let openCards = $(".open");
let list = jQuery.makeArray(openCards);

if(list && list.length > 2)
  return;

$(this).addClass("open show");

openCards = $(".open");
list = jQuery.makeArray(openCards);
if (list.length >= 2) {
      setTimeout(hola, 1000);
      function hola() {
        $(list).removeClass('open show');
      }
}
```

Comment: And if you really wanted, you could first check to see if this card has already been clicked once before. If so, decrement the number of cards and remove the .open class.

Comment: Thanks for that Esaith, but when they match the "match" class is not being added

Comment: I updated my code for that. It's not very pretty, but the same race condition exists between adding the .open class and doing a query against the DOM for .open. The solution isn't very pretty but should work. The codepen site has been updated

Comment: The code has been updated again to keep with jQuery only. The race condition should be removed. If more than 2 cards attempt to be flipped at once time then the third card is not flipped, but this still allows the logic for the 2nd card flipped to continue its check.

Comment: Esaith thanks for that, can you please tell me which part of your code prevents the user to click more than 2 at the same time? THANKS

Comment: if(numOfOpenCards > 2)  return;  prevents more than 2 cards from turning on at the same time. Prior to turning on the card, check to verify 2 arent already turned on. As for https://codepen.io/stivennpe/pen/KRxvxR, comment out line 42. You are removing your click events on all of yours cards which causes the game to stop working as expected.